# parse.com - How to properly secure admin's account?

Tags: parse-platform

We are using parse.com for our mobile application's backend. I'd like to secure my admin's account as much as possible, so as to prevent any intrusion. (I'm talking about the parse's account, and not the mobile application user's account).

Is there any 2-steps authentification process? Or does the security only relies on the admin password?

Thanks for the help,

Answer (score 1):

Parse lets you signup/login using your Facebook, Github or Google account, all of which support two-factor authentication.

Comment: Thanks @MoNazemi. I guess it works for most cases, but I had to set a password anyway (to upload cloud code for instance). Even if I use a Facebook account, one can still try to hack my account using a combination of email / password.

Comment: You should be safe as long as you have a strong password and people do not know the email you are using for you account.